# Is there a command to check if objects in my dynamic array are dynamic or static?

Tags: c++, arrays, dynamic, static, dynamic-arrays

I made a dynamic array with template. The problem is that when I don't keep there pointers (for example: `Tab<string> da;`) my destructor doesn't have to clear it and throws error caused by `delete arr[i];`. My question is if I can put some if condition(in which I would put `clear()` method) which would tell me if my array keeps pointers. In the simplest way I can use `clear()` in main when I keeps there pointers, but my teacher wants me to make it like I wrote above.

I tried using `is_pointer`, but it doesn't work or I use it wrong.
Any suggestions?

```
#ifndef TABLICA_H
#define TABLICA_H

#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

using namespace std;

template<class T>
class Tab
{
public:

int size = 0;
int max_size = 1;
T* arr;
bool isDynamic = false;


Tab()
{
    arr = new T[max_size];
}

~Tab()
{
    clear();
    delete[] arr;
}


void check_size()
{
    if (size == max_size)
    {
        max_size = max_size * 2;
        T* arr2 = new T[max_size];
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        {
            arr2[i] = arr[i];
        }
        delete[] arr;
        arr = arr2;
    }
}

void push_back(const T& value)
{
    check_size();
    arr[size] = value;
    size++;
}

T return_by_index(int index)
{
    if (index<0 || index > size)
    {
        return NULL;
    }
    return arr[index];
}

bool replace(int index, const T& value)
{
    if (index<0 || index > size)
    {
        return false;
    }
    arr[index] = value;
    return true;
}

void print(int number)
{
    cout << "Rozmiar obecny: " << size << endl;
    cout << "Rozmiar maksymalny: " << max_size << endl;
    cout << "Adres tablicy: " << arr << endl;
    cout << "Kilka poczatkowych elementow tablicy " << "(" << number << ")" << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < number; i++)
    {
        cout << *arr[i] << endl;
    }
}

void clear()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        delete arr[i];
    }
}

};

#endif 


//Source:

#include <iostream>

struct object
{
int field1;
char field2;

object()
{
    field1 = rand() % 10001;
    field2 = rand() % 26 + 'A';
}

};

ostream& operator<<(ostream& out, const object& o)
{
return out << o.field1 << " " << o.field2;
}

int main()
{

Tab < object* >* da = new Tab < object* >();
delete da;
system("PAUSE");
return 0;
```

Comment: The question to you is -- why should it matter if the object is static or dynamic?  Your dynamic array shouldn't care or need to know where that pointer that was placed in it by the caller came from.  And the short answer is "no" -- there is no way to determine if your object was allocated from the heap or from the stack.

Comment: "_if my array keeps pointers_" One can have a pointer to non-dynamic object, which you can't delete. e.g.: `Tab < int* > da; int a; da.push_back (&a);`

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius Or the memory could have been allocated with `malloc` or (if Windows), `HeapAlloc` or some other method.  @PowerR -- That's why the container shouldn't be in the business of trying to figure out "where did the memory come from".

Comment: As I understand you write your own `std::vector<T>`. and its only  responsibility to handle memory should be the one it allocates (so your `delete[] arr`). `delete arr[i];` should not be part of the class. user can still use `Tab<std::unique_ptr<T>>` to handle inner memory.

Comment: Just don't `delete` all the elements in the destructor. Even if you did what you're trying to do, you'd end up with `Tab<int>` doing something fundamentally different from `Tab<int*>`.